# How to set value of hidden tag

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I am using `<html:hidden styleId="user" property="issueBranch" value='' />`
For value of `<html:hidden>` i want to set value that i am getting from `<bean:write name="sessionData" property="userId"/>`
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<html:hidden styleId="user" property="issueBranch"/>
```

and in the action which dispatches to the JSP, set the form bean's `issueBranch` property to what you want:

```
myActionForm.setIssueBranch(sessionData.getUserId());
```